# Div slider bug - more than one active slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a div slider to my page. Here is the code:

```js
function selectSlaid(n) {
  var currentSlide = $(".slide.active");
  var nextSlide = $("#slide" + n);
  currentSlide.hide('slide', {
    direction: 'left'
  }, 1000).removeClass("active",
    function() {
      nextSlide.show('slide', {
        direction: 'right'
      }, 1000).addClass("active");
    });
}
```

```css
.slide
{

 display:none;
 
 
}
.slide.active
{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<a href="slider" onClick="selectSlaid(1); return false;">1</a>
<a href="slider" onClick="selectSlaid(2); return false;">2</a>
<a href="slider" onClick="selectSlaid(3); return false;">3</a>
<a href="slider" onClick="selectSlaid(4); return false;">4</a>

<div class="slider">
<div class="slide active" id="slide1"><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p></div>
<div class="slide" id="slide2"><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</p></div>
<div class="slide" id="slide3"><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</p></div>
<div class="slide" id="slide4"><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p></div>
</div>
```

It works, but the problem is that when I click buttons more than once it shows two or more active divs.

I tried in different ways, but I do not know how I can do not show more than one div.

I have four divs that move between each other when pressed on a given button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What calls `selectSlaid`? Please add the relevant code and relevant HTML markup and using the snippet feature add a working example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: It's more/less like this: jsfiddle.net/x6dk4h5d/3 I don't really know why it isn't work on this site. I never used jsfiddle. But here u have code, u can save this like .html. 
Click on links several times, all appear instead of just one. http://www.writeurl.com/publish/wzddkfw116501nxb98ta